# Probability question on sample space

Tags: probability

Recently, I encountered a probability question which can be phrased differently:

Q1: A letter is chosen at random from the word **MISSISSIPPI**. What is the sample space.

Q2: The letters from the word **MISSISSIPPI** are put into a bag. What is the sample space.

Q3: Picking a letter at random from a box containing identical cards with letters that spell the word **MISSISSIPPI**. What is the sample space.

I can understand that the S's, I's and P's are indistinguishable for Q1, and hence the sample space is {M, I, S, P}.

However, my teacher told me that the sample space for Q2 is also {M, I, S, P} which I do not understand. Since each letter is now distinct and distinguished from one another, i.e., the four S's are distinguishable, then why shouldn't the sample space be {M, I1, S1, S2, I2, S3, S4, I3, P1, P2, I4} ?

To make things even more confusing, she said that the sample space for Q3 is {M, I1, S1, S2, I2, S3, S4, I3, P1, P2, I4}.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For Q2, it's still the same sample space because the letters are still indistinguishable. If you pull an `S` at random from the bag (I'm imagining Scrabble tiles here), you still don't know whether it was the first `S` in `MISSISSIPPI` or one of the others.

If we let the random variable $X$ represent the letter drawn, the sample space is still $X\in \{M,I,S,P\}$, with probabilities $P(X=M) = \frac{1}{11}$, $P(X=I) = \frac{4}{11}$, $P(X=S) = \frac{4}{11}$, and $P(X=P) = \frac{2}{11}$.

For Q3, the distinction comes from the cards presumably being ordered. Then, once you've drawn a card, you can tell what position it was in. Each card would have a distinguishable letter *and* position, so each element of the sample space would consist of the letter and its position.

Comment: Thank you @AmaanN for your response. While I can understand your rationale, I found a mathematics textbook which I have screenshot here:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6KtA.png that shows that if there are 3 identical blue balls and 1 red ball in a bag, then the sample set is S={B1, B2, B3, R} instead of S={B,R}. So when do I follow your way and when do I follow the textbook's way? In fact, at the bottom right of the image, it specifically says we cannot write S={B,R}. What's the reason?

Comment: The textbook equivalent in this situation would define the sample space as $\{M_1, I_1, S_1, S_2, I_2, S_3, S_4, I_3, P_1, P_2, I_4 \}$ and the probabilities of each element as equal, while my approach is to define the sample space as $\{M, I, S, P\}$, but with different probabilities for each letter. The end result is the same, it's just a slightly different perspective on what an "event" is - are we counting letter + position, or just letter?